# res.download(NodeJS) not triggering a download on the browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf, download, axios

I've been struggling with this for a while and can't seem to find an answer, I'm developing a website with a budgeting option, I'm sending an object from the client to the server, and that server is using PDFKit to create a PDF version of the budget, once it's created I want to actually send back that PDF to the client and trigger a download, this is what I've done

Client-side code:

```
let data = {
  nombre: this.state.name,
  email: this.state.email,
  telefono: this.state.phone,
  carrito: this.props.budget.cart,
  subTotal: this.props.budget.subTotal,
  IVA: this.props.budget.tax,
  total: this.props.budget.subTotal + this.props.budget.tax
}
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:1337/api/budget',
    data: data
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('This is the response', response);
      window.open('/download')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error);
    })
```

So that data goes to my server-side code perfectly and it looks like this

```
const pdf = require('pdfkit');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

exports.makePDFBudget = (req, res) => {
  let myDoc = new pdf;
  myDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`PDFkit/budget.pdf`));
  myDoc.font('Times-Roman')
       .fontSize(12)
       .text(`${req.body.name} ${req.body.phone} ${req.body.email} ${req.body.cart} ${req.body.subTotal} ${req.body.total} ${req.body.tax}`);
  myDoc.end()
}
```

**That's creating my PDF, what I want now is that once it's created and the response is sent back to the client, the client opens a new window with the URL "/download" which is set to download that PDF, but that's not happening for some reason, it opens up the new window but the download never starts and it throws absolutely no error I'm my Node console or browser console
this is how I send my file to the client**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

exports.downloadPDFBudget = (req, res) => {
  res.download(__dirname + 'budget.pdf', 'budget.pdf');
}
```

And this is how my server index looks like

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const api = express.Router();
const { makePDFBudget } = require('./PDFkit/makePDFBudget.js');
const { downloadPDFBudget } = require('./PDFkit/downloadPDFBudget.js')

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({extended: true}));

api.route('/budget')
  .post(makePDFBudget)

api.route('/download')
  .get(downloadPDFBudget)

app.use('/api', api);

const port = 1337;

app.listen(port);

console.log('Listening on port ', port);

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it, the port in which I was running my client obviously was different from the one I was running my server, so I had to open a window to my server's port to trigger the download, I realized this because I threw a console log on the function that was supposed to do the res.download it wasn't showing up. Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on how you did that please?

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess the main problem here:

   res.download(__dirname + 'budget.jpg', 'budget.pdf');

   Make a correct file name. Your file is pdf, not jpg.
2. At this code `res.end(Buffer.from('budget.pdf'))` you sending string, not file content. But headers like you want to send a file.
3. The last. Your application designed like you will have only one user. Could you add userId to file names? Or use DB for storing data and generate pdf on request without storing a file to the file system.

Comment: 1. Yeah, the jpg was because I was trying with a different file that wasn't a PDF to check if that was the problem but that was not it, it still doesn't work after fixing that (I used to have it like that)

2. I was trying to send the PDF on the response of the request but then opted for just making the client open the /download URL and never got rid of that.

3. The way that I want it is that I just want to send that PDF back to the client's browser and an email to the company's email address and then delete it, without any kind of user or auth

I will update the code to the correct way

Comment: No, that didn't solve it, I updated my code and also the question, but it's still not working, I tried instead of opening a new window to the /download URL doing an AJAX request to that route and got a response with data but it's a string which makes no sense